# Do all linux commands exist in cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin

I want to use the command more to see the content of a text file; however, the command is not available. I wonder whether all linux commands exist in cygwin. I am running cygwin on windows xp.

Comment: iptables, tc, lsusb, depmod, and many, many more.

Comment: Have you tried "less"?

Answer (score 5):

No. All Linux commands don't even exist in all versions of Linux.  I am not sure if your specific command exists in Cygwin, but if you cannot find it, it probably isn't there (though "more" is a pretty common command to be excluded).

Comment: It really depends how much or how little of Cygwin is installed.  It's like many Linux distros where you can choose what packages you want to install.

Answer (score 2):

`more` is available in Cygwin if it's not in the default install. I prefer to use `less` myself.

To answer your question, "all" is awfully broad, but (very) many of the usual utilities are available in Cygwin.

Comment: well, `less` is more flexible and is way more useful than `more`. In that sense, `less` definitely is more

Answer (score 2):

"more" is available in my install of Cygwin on XP, which I'm fairly sure is default. You need to make sure you have the "util-linux" package installed, which includes all sorts of useful utilities.

A full list of the packages is available at http://cygwin.com/packages/

Answer (score 0):

#### "Yes"

Well, not really "all", but lots and lots.

However, Cygwin was an early pioneer of the package-based install, and because it doesn't have to actually run the host OS, more things are optional in Cygwin than in other Linux distros. The initial install is definitely a lot smaller.

So, you will find yourself going back to the installer more often on Cygwin, in oreder to drag in a package that just wasn't in the base system.

Comment: the answer is "no", and not a bold "yes" and then explaining that its only a "half-yes .. or maybe a 30% yes" ...

Comment: -1 @DigitalRoss you will small distros like Arch lack many commands that you would find in other larger distros like Ubuntu or RHEL. You will lose even more commands when working with specialty distros like DD-WRT